# Why Flutter ListTile onTap seems cached?

Tags: flutter

I have two listview screen on my app. User can navigate between them using BottomNavigationBar control.

On listview.builder function, I return something like this

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text('...'),
                      subtitle: Text('...'),
                      onTap:  () { 
                ...
                      }
                   )
                });
```

I found onTap handler seems mixed between those 2 listviews.

When I open first list view, flutter serve the correct onTap,but when I switch to second listview, flutter still serving the first listview onTap.

[image]

Seems the onTap is cached by flutter (title & subtitle seems okay). Any idea?

Sample source code: https://github.com/jazarja/flutter_app

Comment: That sounds like there is some mistake in your code. To investigate we would need a complete runnable but still minimal reproduction.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have upload sample source code on https://github.com/jazarja/flutter_app

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your compararing transition values. Because you are first reversing the animation transition of current view.


In your **botton_nav.dart**, change this:

```
return aValue.compareTo(bValue);
```

to this:

```
return bValue.compareTo(aValue);
```

Comment: Seems not working. Second list ontap will be served for first list tap event. See [link](https://github.com/jazarja/flutter_app/raw/master/flutter_issue2.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is that the animations haven't completed by the time the comparison is being done so the widget at the top of the stack is always 1 tab selection behind.  You actually don't need to build a stack at all, just replace `Center(child: _buildTransitionStack())` [here](https://github.com/jazarja/flutter_app/blob/master/lib/screens/bottom_nav.dart#L202) with `_navigationViews[_currentIndex].transition(_type, context)` and it should work.